# Integrate a normal map via a 2D gradient field

Tags: c++, mathematics, cuda

This code transforms a normal map into a 2D gradient field and then iteratively integrates it to a likely solution.

I don't have a lot of experience with C++/CUDA yet and would appreciate some advice mainly on the code style specific to C++ (I come from a C# background). Any advice on increasing performance would also be appreciated (using shared CUDA memory comes to my mind and I might implement that later).

This is one of the simpler and better documented parts of my project, although understanding what the code does might need some background knowledge given in the two studies linked in the comments, but I think a full understanding should hopefully not be needed for a code review. The functions and types I used and are not found inside the code I posted should be self explanatory (hopefully).

````
namespace solver::gradient_integrator
{
  /** Transforms the normals into a gradient field with gradient = diff(height). */
  __global__ void calc_gradient(const unsigned width, const unsigned height, const normal_type* normals, float2* gradient)
  {
    const auto x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    const auto y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if (x >= width || y >= height) return;
    const auto image_index_dst = get_image_index(width, x, y);
    const auto normal = normals[get_image_index(width, between(0u, x, width - 1), between(0u, y, height - 1))];
    const auto normal_f = convert<vec3>(normal);
    const auto mag = norm(normal_f);
    const auto grad_x = between_nan(-10.f, -tan(asin(normal_f.x / mag)), 10.f);
    const auto grad_y = between_nan(-10.f, -tan(asin(normal_f.y / mag)), 10.f);
    gradient[image_index_dst] = {grad_x, grad_y};
  }

  /** Scales the source to the target by the scaling parameter using bilinear interpolation, missing values are extrapolated from the nearest edge. */
  template <typename T>
  __global__ void scale(const unsigned source_width, const unsigned source_height, const unsigned target_width, const unsigned target_height, const float scaling, const T* source, T* target)
  {
    const auto x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    const auto y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if (x >= target_width || y >= target_height) return;

    const auto pos_x = (static_cast<float>(x) + 0.5f) / scaling;
    const auto pos_y = (static_cast<float>(y) + 0.5f) / scaling;
    const auto pos_xm1 = roundf(pos_x) - 0.5f;
    const auto pos_xp1 = pos_xm1 + 1;
    const auto pos_ym1 = roundf(pos_y) - 0.5f;
    const auto pos_yp1 = pos_ym1 + 1;
    const auto idx_xm1 = static_cast<unsigned>(pos_xm1);
    const auto idx_xp1 = idx_xm1 + 1;
    const auto idx_ym1 = static_cast<unsigned>(pos_ym1);
    const auto idx_yp1 = idx_ym1 + 1;

    target[get_image_index(target_width, x, y)] = (pos_x - pos_xm1) * (pos_y - pos_ym1) * source[get_image_index_s(source_width, source_height, idx_xp1, idx_yp1)] +
      (pos_x - pos_xm1) * (pos_yp1 - pos_y) * source[get_image_index_s(source_width, source_height, idx_xp1, idx_ym1)] +
      (pos_xp1 - pos_x) * (pos_y - pos_ym1) * source[get_image_index_s(source_width, source_height, idx_xm1, idx_yp1)] +
      (pos_xp1 - pos_x) * (pos_yp1 - pos_y) * source[get_image_index_s(source_width, source_height, idx_xm1, idx_ym1)];
  }

  /** Multiplies all values inside the target array by the given factor. */
  template <typename T>
  __global__ void multiply(const unsigned width, const unsigned height, const float factor, T* target)
  {
    const auto x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    const auto y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if (x >= width || y >= height) return;
    target[get_image_index(width, x, y)] *= factor;
  }

  /**
   * Locally integrates the gradient using the neighboring gradients and previous height estimate.
   *
   * The height arrays need to have double the width and height than the gradient, as integrating the gradient to an array the same size would lead to
   * slight inaccuracies which are likely not tolerable in the scope of this project. Only half the entries in the height arrays are used for the actual height though, 
   * the rest is temporarily used for a momentum value of the "gradient descent".
   */
  __global__ void iterative_integrate(const unsigned grad_width, const unsigned grad_height, const bool set_velocity_zero, const float2* gradient, const float* prev_res, float* res)
  {
    // Similar methods are described here:
    // Iterative integration of gradients:
    //    https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281050028_GPU-based_photometric_reconstruction_from_screen_light
    // Optimization of above paper by using a pyramid representation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(image_processing):
    //    https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228732828_Pyramidal_Normal_Map_Integration_for_Real-time_Photometric_Stereo

    // sketch for positions of the gradient (+) and height values (.)
    // + . + . + . + .
    // .   .   .   . 
    // + . + . + . + .
    // .   .   .   .
    // + . + . + . + .
    const int swidth = static_cast<int>(grad_width);
    const int sheight = static_cast<int>(grad_height);
    const int res_width = swidth * 2;
    const int res_height = sheight * 2;
    const auto hx = static_cast<int>(blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x);
    const bool horizontal = hx % 2 == 1; // denoting if the adjacent gradients are next to the current position on the x axis (horizontal) or on the y axis (vertical)
    const auto hy = static_cast<int>(blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y) * 2 + (horizontal ? 0 : 1);
    if (hx >= res_width || hy >= res_height) return;
    const auto velocity_idx = get_image_index(res_width, hx + (horizontal ? -1 : 1), hy);
    const auto hidx = get_image_index(res_width, hx, hy);
    const auto h_xm1_ym1 = prev_res[get_image_index_s(res_width, res_height, hx - 1, hy - 1)];
    const auto h_xm1_yp1 = prev_res[get_image_index_s(res_width, res_height, hx - 1, hy + 1)];
    const auto h_xp1_ym1 = prev_res[get_image_index_s(res_width, res_height, hx + 1, hy - 1)];
    const auto h_xp1_yp1 = prev_res[get_image_index_s(res_width, res_height, hx + 1, hy + 1)];
    float newval;
    if (horizontal)
    {
      const auto h_xm2_y0 = prev_res[get_image_index_s(res_width, res_height, hx - 2, hy)];
      const auto h_xp2_y0 = prev_res[get_image_index_s(res_width, res_height, hx + 2, hy)];
      const auto g_xm1 = gradient[get_image_index_s(swidth, sheight, hx / 2, hy / 2)];
      const auto g_xp1 = gradient[get_image_index_s(swidth, sheight, hx / 2 + 1, hy / 2)];
      newval = (
        (h_xm2_y0 + g_xm1.x) + (h_xp2_y0 - g_xp1.x) +
        (h_xm1_ym1 + g_xm1.x / 2 + g_xm1.y / 2) / 2 +
        (h_xm1_yp1 + g_xm1.x / 2 - g_xm1.y / 2) / 2 +
        (h_xp1_ym1 - g_xp1.x / 2 + g_xp1.y / 2) / 2 +
        (h_xp1_yp1 - g_xp1.x / 2 - g_xp1.y / 2) / 2
      ) / 4;
    }
    else
    {
      const auto h_x0_ym2 = prev_res[get_image_index_s(res_width, res_height, hx, hy - 2)];
      const auto h_x0_yp2 = prev_res[get_image_index_s(res_width, res_height, hx, hy + 2)];
      const auto g_ym1 = gradient[get_image_index_s(swidth, sheight, hx / 2, hy / 2)];
      const auto g_yp1 = gradient[get_image_index_s(swidth, sheight, hx / 2, hy / 2 + 1)];
      newval = (
        (h_x0_ym2 + g_ym1.y) + (h_x0_yp2 - g_yp1.y) +
        (h_xm1_ym1 + g_ym1.x / 2 + g_ym1.y / 2) / 2 +
        (h_xp1_ym1 - g_ym1.x / 2 + g_ym1.y / 2) / 2 +
        (h_xm1_yp1 + g_yp1.x / 2 - g_yp1.y / 2) / 2 +
        (h_xp1_yp1 - g_yp1.x / 2 - g_yp1.y / 2) / 2
      ) / 4;
    }
    const auto diff = newval - res[hidx];
    const auto velocity = 0.5f * (set_velocity_zero ? 0.f : prev_res[velocity_idx]) + diff * 0.5f;
    res[hidx] += velocity;
    res[velocity_idx] = velocity;
  }

  /** After calling the iterative_deconvolve method, only half the entries are filled inside the height array, this method interpolates missing values from their neighbors. */
  __global__ void fill_gaps(const unsigned width, const unsigned height, const float* res_m1, float* res)
  {
    const int swidth = static_cast<int>(width);
    const int sheight = static_cast<int>(height);
    const auto hx = static_cast<int>(blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x);
    const auto hy = static_cast<int>(blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y);
    const bool empty = !(hx % 2 == 0 ^ hy % 2 == 0);
    if (hx >= swidth || hy >= sheight) return;
    const auto hidx = get_image_index(swidth, hx, hy);
    if (empty)
    {
      res[hidx] = (res_m1[get_image_index_s(swidth, sheight, hx - 1, hy)] +
        res_m1[get_image_index_s(swidth, sheight, hx + 1, hy)] +
        res_m1[get_image_index_s(swidth, sheight, hx, hy - 1)] +
        res_m1[get_image_index_s(swidth, sheight, hx, hy + 1)]) / 4;
    }
    else res[hidx] = res_m1[hidx];
  }

  struct gradient_field
  {
    const size_t width;
    const size_t height;
    float2* gradients;

    gradient_field(size_t width, size_t height, float2* gradients)
      : width(width),
        height(height),
        gradients(gradients)
    {
    }
  };

  /**
   * See integrate(const image<normal_type>& normals, image<float>& out, float& factor).
   *
   * This function already uses arrays copied to the GPU.
   */
  void integrate(const size_t width, const size_t height, const normal_type* d_normals, float*& d_height)
  {
    debug::log_region region("integrating normal map");

    constexpr auto thread_count = 16;
    dim3 threads(thread_count, thread_count);
    dim3 gradient_blocks((static_cast<unsigned>(width) + thread_count - 1) / thread_count, (static_cast<unsigned>(height) + thread_count - 1) / thread_count);
    float2* d_gradient;
    check_error(cudaMalloc(&d_gradient, width * height * sizeof(float2)));

    calc_gradient << <gradient_blocks, threads >> >(static_cast<unsigned>(width), static_cast<unsigned>(height), d_normals, d_gradient); // NOLINT

    // build gradient pyramid
    constexpr float scaling = 2.0f;
    std::stack<gradient_field> pyramid{};
    const auto max_size = std::max(width, height);
    const auto iterations = static_cast<int>(log2(max_size) - 5.);
    auto current_width = width;
    auto current_height = height;
    size_t last_width;
    size_t last_height;
    pyramid.emplace(width, height, d_gradient);
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
      last_width = current_width;
      last_height = current_height;
      current_width = (current_width + 1) / 2;
      current_height = (current_height + 1) / 2;
      check_error(cudaMalloc(&d_gradient, current_width * current_height * sizeof(float2)));
      dim3 scale_blocks((static_cast<unsigned>(current_width) * 2 + thread_count - 1) / thread_count, (static_cast<unsigned>(current_height) * 2 + thread_count - 1) / thread_count);
      scale << <scale_blocks, threads >> >(last_width, last_height, current_width, current_height, 1.f / scaling, pyramid.top().gradients, d_gradient); // NOLINT
      multiply << <scale_blocks, threads >> >(current_width, current_height, scaling, d_gradient); // NOLINT
      pyramid.emplace(current_width, current_height, d_gradient);
    }

    // iterate pyramid top to bottom and use the upscaled previous results as a starting point of a new layer
    float* last_result = nullptr;
    while (!pyramid.empty())
    {
      last_width = current_width;
      last_height = current_height;
      current_width = static_cast<unsigned>(pyramid.top().width);
      current_height = static_cast<unsigned>(pyramid.top().height);
      d_gradient = pyramid.top().gradients;
      float *d_out, *d_out_prev;
      check_error(cudaMalloc(&d_out, 2 * current_width * 2 * current_height * sizeof(float)));
      check_error(cudaMalloc(&d_out_prev, 2 * current_width * 2 * current_height * sizeof(float)));
      dim3 fill_blocks((static_cast<unsigned>(current_width) * 2 + thread_count - 1) / thread_count, (static_cast<unsigned>(current_height) * 2 + thread_count - 1) / thread_count);
      dim3 iter_blocks((static_cast<unsigned>(current_width) * 2 + thread_count - 1) / thread_count, (static_cast<unsigned>(current_height) + thread_count - 1) / thread_count);
      if (last_result != nullptr)
      {
        scale << <fill_blocks, threads >> >(last_width * 2, last_height * 2, current_width * 2, current_height * 2, scaling, last_result, d_out_prev); // NOLINT
        check_error(cudaFree(last_result));
      }
      {
        const size_t current_iterations = opt_settings::height_iterations * (width / current_width); //increase iterations for smaller widths
        for (size_t i = 0; i < current_iterations; i++)
        {
          iterative_integrate << <iter_blocks, threads >> >(static_cast<unsigned>(current_width), static_cast<unsigned>(current_height), i == 0, d_gradient, d_out_prev, d_out); // NOLINT

          float* res = d_out;
          d_out = d_out_prev;
          d_out_prev = res;
        }
      }
      fill_gaps << <fill_blocks, threads >> >(static_cast<unsigned>(current_width) * 2, static_cast<unsigned>(current_height) * 2, d_out_prev, d_out); // NOLINT
      last_result = d_out;
      check_error(cudaFree(d_out_prev));
      check_error(cudaFree(d_gradient));
      pyramid.pop();
    }
    d_height = last_result;
  }

  /**
   * Integrates the given normals and returns a height field with double the width and height of the input.\n
   * The height field is normalized to [0,1] with the returned factor denoting the scaling to multiply by, in order to get the original value.\n
   * The dimensions of the height field are given by max(width, height) of the normal field.
   */
  void integrate(const image<normal_type>& normals, image<float>& height, float& factor)
  {
    normal_type* d_normals;
    float* d_height = nullptr;
    cudaMalloc(&d_normals, normals.width * normals.height * sizeof(normal_type));
    check_error(cudaMemcpy(d_normals, normals.data.data(), normals.width * normals.height * sizeof(normal_type), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    integrate(normals.width, normals.height, d_normals, d_height);
    height.resize(normals.width * 2, normals.height * 2);
    check_error(cudaMemcpy(height.data.data(), d_height, height.width * height.height * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    cudaFree(d_height);

    auto min = 1e10f;
    auto max = -1e10f;
    for (const auto pixel : height.data)
    {
      if (pixel < min) min = pixel;
      if (pixel > max) max = pixel;
    }
    const auto image_size_1d = static_cast<float>(max_(normals.height, normals.width));
    factor = (max - min) / image_size_1d;
    printf("\n%.6f\n", static_cast<double>((max - min) / image_size_1d));
    for (auto& pixel : height.data) pixel = (pixel - min) / (max - min);
  }

  /**
   * Differentiates the given height field and returns a gradient field in the form of normals with half the width and height as the input.\n
   * The height field is scaled by the provided factor.
   */
  void differentiate(const image<float>& height, image<normal_type>& normal, const float factor)
  {
    normal.resize(height.width / 2, height.height / 2);
    for (size_t x = 0; x < normal.width; x++)
    {
      for (size_t y = 0; y < normal.height; y++)
      {
        const bool corner_x = x == 0 || x == normal.width - 1;
        const bool corner_y = y == 0 || y == normal.height - 1;
        const auto norm_x = sin(atan(factor * static_cast<float>(normal.height) * (corner_x ? 2.f : 1.f) *
          (height.data[get_image_index_s(height.width, height.height, x * 2 - 1, y * 2)] - height.data[get_image_index_s(height.width, height.height, x * 2 + 1, y * 2)])));
        const auto norm_y = sin(atan(factor * static_cast<float>(normal.height) * (corner_y ? 2.f : 1.f) *
          (height.data[get_image_index_s(height.width, height.height, x * 2, y * 2 - 1)] - height.data[get_image_index_s(height.width, height.height, x * 2, y * 2 + 1)])));
        const auto norm_z = sqrt(1 - norm_x * norm_x - norm_y * norm_y);
        normal[ulonglong2{x, y}] = {norm_x, norm_y, norm_z};
      }
    }
  }
}
```
````